# Loading issue in WebBrowser control for httpwebresponse in WP7 & 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, httpwebresponse

I am trying to load web browser with the html code from the httpwebresponse by storing it in a string variable.

I created  a httpwebrequest for a URL by setting cookies in it and getting a html page in a httpwebResponse.

I am trying to display it in a web browser control by saving the code in a string variable. And navigating the browser("browse.NavigateToString(string)").

But here page is not loaded properly.It is not displaying any css or images and displaying a message"You need to turn on java script in order to display the contents".

I made the web browser property (IsScriptEnabled ) true before navigation. But it is still showing the message and contents are not loaded properly.

Cookies are also not injected in to the web browser controls(session is not maintained through out the app).

Is there any solution or work around for this ??

Please refer to the below code :
**To log cookies  from login service :**

private void PostLoginRequest()
        {

```
        string AuthServiceUri = "Service URL";
        HttpWebRequest AuthReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(AuthServiceUri) as HttpWebRequest;
        AuthReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        AuthReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        AuthReq.Method = "POST";

        AuthReq.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), AuthReq);
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;

        Stream postStream = Request.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
        string postData = "Postdata parameters";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), Request);

    }

    void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {

        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest callBackRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

            CookieCollection cookiecollec = new CookieCollection();
            cookiecollec = response.Cookies;
            App.cookieCollection = cookiecollec; //global varaiable

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Another httpwebrequest with logged cookies :**

private void ResponsivePostURL(string PageName, string PostURL, string PostDatas)
             {

```
                    Uri ServiceUri = new Uri(PostURL); //Service URL

                    HttpWebRequest requestURL = HttpWebRequest.CreateServiceUri as HttpWebRequest;
                    requestURL.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    requestURL.Method = "POST";                        
                    requestURL.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    requestURL.CookieContainer.Add(ServiceUri, App.cookieCollection);

                    requestURL.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), requestURL); 


             }
```

void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
             {

```
             try
             {

                 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
                 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);


                // MessageBox.Show(response.Cookies.ToString());

                 string responseString = "<html><head></head><body>";
                 Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                 responseString = responseString + reader.ReadToEnd() + "</body></html>";                   
                 streamResponse.Close();
                 reader.Close();
                 response.Close();



                 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                 {

                     webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
                     webBrowser.NavigateToString(responseString);

                 });
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }
         }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the html content you're receiving from WebResponse is proper? Just curious... try to save the response in a notepad file, set extension as .html and try to open in IE desktop.

Comment: That's odd. I'm downloading dynamic content using WP7.x/WP8.x from e.g. EA websites that use heavily javascript and JSON content and everything is working fine. Maybe you could copy/paste some of your core code here?

Comment: @Abhishek..How can i test that the html content from the web response is proper ??

Comment: @Mikki Viitala Please refer to my code sample below.The main problem I am facing is I need to maintain a session in hybrid app.Once the user logged in in app..I am trying to save the cookies and injecting the cookies to web browser for further request inorder to make the user logged in till the session ends.

Comment: I saved the html code and opened in IE desktop.It is displaying the same page without images css as like in web browser of windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to the site and save the document, you are not getting the  `script`, `css` nor `image` files (and any other resource for that matter) but only the static/generated HTML document as-is, which probably refer to  those files using relative paths. If paths are not absolute, scripts/css/images/other resources are not found.

If you want to make it work, you need to replace relative paths with absolute paths within the HTML file.

So if you have

`<script src="/scripts/cool.js"></script>`

You'd replace it with

`<script src="http://www.thesite.com/scripts/cool.js"></script>`

(Note that this is just my best guess, not something I have actually tried out :)